# Chai expect to be one of array elements

Tags: javascript, bdd, chai

Is there any way to assert that `string` is one of `array` elements with chai bdd? I couldn't find that in [Chai API](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/)

```
expect("bar").to.be.one.of(["bar", "key"]);
```

Comment: Try: `expect('bar').to.satisfy(function(bar) { return ['bar','foo'].some(function(str) { return str === bar; }); });`. Links: [`satisfy`](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#-satisfy-method-), [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Comment: This seems to work `expect("bar").to.be.a('string').and.be.oneOf([‌​'girigamba','bar','f‌​oo']).and.not.empty;`

I think in your question `one.of` should be `oneOf`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Flip the check around:

```
expect(["bar", "key"]).to.include("bar");
```

Comment: It doesn't work if we use chai-as-expected and 'bar', which should be one of a list, is actually a promise.

Comment: Then you would simply put your assertion of the value from the promise return into the .then block and check the result there.

Answer (score 10):

Updated for 2021

The answer below prints out a better error message

```
expect(res.status).to.be.oneOf([400, 401]);
```

The error message clearly defines what the expected value is and the returned value.

E.g.

```
expect(200).to.be.oneOf([400, 401]);
```

Returns

`AssertionError: expected 200 to be one of [ 400, 401 ]`