# Chai expect that result equals one of three options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme, chai

I am using enzyme and chai to test my React application. I want to write an expectation that tests that the result is equal to one of three possible options. 
For example (sudo code):

`expect(result).to.eq('red').or('green').or('yellow');`

or

`expect(result).to.beOneOf(['red','green','yellow']);`

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution on stackoverflow
[Chai expect to be one of array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32662162/chai-expect-to-be-one-of-array-elements)

Looks like I can switch my expectation around like this"
`expect(['red', 'yellow', 'green']).to.include(result);`